# Filter collection based on values in array in Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an array of unique values:

```
const array = [1, 2, 4]
```

I have a collection of unique objects:

```
const collection = [
  { type: 1, eyes: 'blue'},
  { type: 2, eyes: 'brown'},
  { type: 3, eyes: 'green'},
  { type: 4, eyes: 'blue'}
]
```

Using Ramda how do I extract all the objects from `collection` where type is included in `array`?

Expected outcome:

```
[
  { type: 1, eyes: 'blue'},
  { type: 2, eyes: 'brown'},
  { type: 4, eyes: 'blue'}
]
```

Comment: This is not ramda but you can define a filter function taking getter and compare function and compose multiple of these to create powerful array filters. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075368/1641941)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`R.innerJoin()`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#innerJoin):

```js
const array = [1, 2, 4]
const collection = [{ type: 1, eyes: 'blue'},{ type: 2, eyes: 'brown'}, { type: 3, eyes: 'green'}, { type: 4, eyes: 'blue'}]

const joinByType = R.innerJoin(
  (o, type) => o.type === type
)

const result = joinByType(collection, array)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

The same method in a more ramdaish way using [`R.propEq()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#propEq) to compare the `type` property with the type id from the array. We need to use [`R.flip()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#flip) because innerJoin passes the object before the the value to compare to.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 4]
const collection = [{ type: 1, eyes: 'blue'},{ type: 2, eyes: 'brown'}, { type: 3, eyes: 'green'}, { type: 4, eyes: 'blue'}]

const joinByType = R.innerJoin(R.flip(R.propEq('type')))

const result = joinByType(collection, array)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if someone is missing the typescript types for innerJoin, just add this:

declare module 'ramda' {
  interface Static {
    innerJoin<T, U>(fn: (v: U, p: T) => boolean, x1: U[], x2: T[]): U[];
  }
}

Comment: How to get the missing items ?
[
  { type: 3, eyes: 'green'}
]

Comment: Reverse the condition - `const joinByType = R.innerJoin(
  (o, type) => o.type !== type
)` (note the `!==`).

Answer (score 1):

Without ramda

```
collection.filter(item => array.includes(item.type))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer from Mukesh Soni is what you need for this.  In Ramda, it might read `filter(p => array.includes(p.type), collection)`, but that's much the same.

But Ramda is all about *functions*, and creating reusable and flexible functions to handle your needs.  I would at least consider writing something like this:

```js
const {curry, filter, contains, prop} = R

const collection = [{ type: 1, eyes: 'blue'},{ type: 2, eyes: 'brown'}, { type: 3, eyes: 'green'}, { type: 4, eyes: 'blue'}]
const array = [1, 2, 4]

const filterBy = curry((propName, selectedValues, collection) => 
  filter(e => contains(prop(propName, e), selectedValues), collection))

const newCollection = filterBy('type', array, collection)

console.log(newCollection)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

I might even go one step further, and allow for an arbitrary transformation function, rather than just `prop`:

```
const filterBy = curry((transform, selectedValues, collection) => 
  filter(e => selectedValues.includes(transform(e)), collection))

filterBy(prop('type'), array, collection)
```

But abstractions such as these are generally only helpful if you expect to make other use of them across your application.  If this is the only place where you use a list of values to match with in order to filter a collection, then there is little reason for any reusable function.