# Currying with filter

Tags: javascript, currying

```
let dragons = [
    { name: "Test1", power: "Fire" },
    { name: "Test2", power: "Lightning" },
    { name: "Test3", power: "Fire" },
    { name: "Test4", power: "Fire" },
    { name: "Test5", power: "Speed" },
    { name: "Test6", power: "Fly" }
];

let hasPower = power =>
    obj => 
        obj.power === power

let fireDragons = dragons.filter(hasPower("Fire"));
```

I get the currying part, but what I don't get is how the currying function gets passed obj from filter, can someone explain that to me?

Comment: If I told you calling filter this way is equivalent to: `hasPower("Fire")(dragons[index])` for each dragon, would that help?

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will pass each item of the dragons array to the function you pass it.

More on filter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075368/1641941)

Comment: I get that's how currying works, but what I don't understand is how the dragon object is getting passed to hasPower

Comment: That's the magic HMR just commented on...it is a callback feature of `filter()`

Comment: To be correct; each dragon is passed to hasPower("Fire")

Comment: It would help if you used regular functions instead of arrow functions. Try it!

Comment: Right, misworded I'm going to read that doc you just sent, if you would like you can post that with your answer

Comment: Each dragon object is passed to the return value of `hasPower` which is also a function.

Comment: Because your `hasPower` function returns a callback function for filter where `obj` param will be each object from dragons array inside filter.

Comment: To really understand how Array#filter iterates through the array to send the each element value to the filter callback, you may need to study its Polyfill provided here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before understanding the code you shared, let's first learn the syntax of the filter function.

```
var newArray = arr.filter(callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])
```

> **callback** Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise, taking three arguments: `element`, `index` and the `array` itself. `thisArg` is optional, though.

Now, let's try to understand the code.

```
let hasPower = power =>
    obj => 
        obj.power === power
```

The function `hasPower` can be updated as:

```
let hasPower = function (power) {
    return function (obj) {
        return obj.power === power;
    }
}
```

Just keep in mind, whenever `hasPower` would be executed, it will simply return a function (which would be executed later) and will have access to the `power` variable. (Read more: [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures))

and now the fireDragons,

```
let fireDragons = dragons.filter(hasPower("Fire"));
```

You are passing a function as a parameter to the filter function (**invoking** it as well).

When this line of code is executed, the function `hasPower("Fire")` would be executed first and whatever is returned from that function would be passed to the filter as the `callback` function.

Basically, it would become something like:

```
let fireDragons = dragons.filter(function (obj) {
    // Having access to the `hasPower` variable which is "Fire" in your case.
    return obj.power === power;
});
```

or exactly like this:
[image]

Always try to debug in the developer tools to understand how the code works and feel free to replace the arrow functions with regular ones to make it more readable/understandable.