# Filtering an array with objects with another array with strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have 2 arrays and I want to filter one of the arrays with another array.

2 arrays designed like this

```
array1= [{id:23},{id:11},{id:435}]

array2= [23, 435, 5]
```

I want to check and get items only if id of objects inside array1 is equal to one of the ids (string values ) in array2

I found a simple solution like this

```
var filtered=[1,2,3,4].filter(function(e){return this.indexOf(e)<0;},[2,4]);
```

but my case is a bit different, I dont know how to make return part, how can I get indexes of each array ?

```
var filtered=array1.filter(function(e){return e.id === ??},array2);
```

Comment: please add the wanted result. why do you need to use `this`?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075368/1641941) explains about filtering. Look for `more complex comparer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just look up the index by using the `id` property.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 23 }, { id: 11 }, { id: 435 }],
    array2 = [23, 435, 5],
    filtered = array1.filter(function (o) {
        return array2.indexOf(o.id) > -1;
    });
    
console.log(filtered);
```

ES6

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 23 }, { id: 11 }, { id: 435 }],
    array2 = [23, 435, 5],
    filtered = array1.filter(({ id }) => array2.includes(id));
    
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: thanks but it only worked when I make it > -1 instead of  < 0 I think you thought it reverse

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter` and essentially check if the object `id` exists in `array2`. There are several ways to do that including `.find` and `.findIndex`. I would use `.some` which returns `true` if a single match is found.

```
array1.filter(obj => array2.some(id => id === obj.id));
```