# Script work in a browser but not in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm struggling trying to understand why this script works perfectly in the browser but not in Node.js in the server.

```js
data = [{"stars": 3}, {"stars": 2}]

var ParseParameter = function(){
    this.parser = "";
}

ParseParameter.prototype = {
    setStrategy: function(parser) {
        this.parser = parser;
    },
 
    parse: function(parameter) {
        return this.parser.parse(parameter);
    }
};


var IntegerParser = function(filter){

    this.parameter = '';
    this.filter = filter;

    this.parse = function(parameter){
        this.parameter = parseInt(parameter); 
    }

    this.filterBy = function(item){
        return item[this.filter] == this.parameter;
    }
}

var filter = 'stars',
    parameter = '2',
    parseParameter = new ParseParameter();

var integerParser = new IntegerParser(filter);
    parseParameter.setStrategy(integerParser);
    parseParameter.parse(parameter);
    
    var dataFiltered = data.filter(parseParameter.parser.filterBy);

    console.log(dataFiltered);
```

At the server, I print in console the values of `this.parameter` and `this.filter` at the function `filterBy` and these are `undefined`

I'm running on Node.js version 8.11.2

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: It may be because of wrapper function in Node.js. this keyword varies in Node

Comment: You could use higher order functions instead of OO. An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075368/1641941)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The is may be due to problem of `this` keyword in your script. Inside an inner function `this` refers to `window` or `global` object. For example,

Inside the following code, `this.filter` of `this.filterBy` is not referring to the filter property that exists inside the scope of `IntegerParser` function instead it is referring the variable being defined as `var filter = 'stars'`. Change this name to something else and you'll see `undefined` and it won't work on browser as well. That's what could be your issue.

```
var IntegerParser = function(filter){

    this.parameter = '';
    this.filter = filter;

    this.parse = function(parameter){
        this.parameter = parseInt(parameter); 
    }

    this.filterBy = function(item){
        return item[this.filter] == this.parameter;
    }
}
```

Instead of using `this` you could use a known solution for this problem by  storing `this` to a variable for later usage. like in following example:

```
var IntegerParser = function(filter){

        this.parameter = '';
        this.filter = filter;
        var self = this;  // store this to self and use self in inner functions

        this.parse = function(parameter){
            self.parameter = parseInt(parameter); 
        }

        this.filterBy = function(item){
            return item[self.filter] == self.parameter;
        }
    }
```

Your entire code including my solution is as follow:

```js
data = [{"stars": 3}, {"stars": 2}]

var ParseParameter = function(){
    this.parser = "";
}

ParseParameter.prototype = {
    setStrategy: function(parser) {
        this.parser = parser;
    },
 
    parse: function(parameter) {
        return this.parser.parse(parameter);
    }
};


var IntegerParser = function(filter){

    this.parameter = '';
    this.filter = filter;
    var self = this;

    this.parse = function(parameter){
        self.parameter = parseInt(parameter); 
    }

    this.filterBy = function(item){        
        return item[self.filter] == self.parameter;
    }
}
var filter = 'stars',
    parameter = '2',
    parseParameter = new ParseParameter();

var integerParser = new IntegerParser(filter);
    parseParameter.setStrategy(integerParser);
    parseParameter.parse(parameter);
    
    var dataFiltered = data.filter(parseParameter.parser.filterBy);

    console.log(dataFiltered);
```

It should work without any problem. Please try and see if it works for you.

Comment: Why is 'this' for inner function 'parse' is same as 'IntegerParser' but for 'fiterBy' function is Global object? Since 'this.parse' and 'this.filterBy' both are inner functions.

Comment: @Vishal-Lia It is because we are assigning a new object to prototype of  `ParseParameter`. In case of objects the `this` refers to the object itself.

Comment: How would be in case I use the prototype syntax, I mean, instead of `this.filterBy ` write `IntegerParse.protoype.filterBy`, how could I attach the context?

Comment: @JoseRojas You can in that case use JavaScript's `call` or `apply` or `bind` methods for specifying the context or reference of `this` keyword. 

Read more here: https://medium.com/@omergoldberg/javascript-call-apply-and-bind-e5c27301f7bb