# javascript - better search value script in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to search for a value in nested array to answer the question :

Is there **an emailAddress** of `"type":"CONTACT"` with `"value":"email4@example.com"`?

I wrote the following basic algorithm (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erwin16/ytwjg8oL/)) which is giving the expected result, but I guess there is a better and shorter way to solve it ...

```
const infos = [
    {
        "resourceName":"name1",
        "id":"id1",
        "emailAddresses":[
            { "metadata":{ "primary":true,  "source":{ "type":"CONTACT", "id":"m1" } , "value":"email1@example.com"}},
            { "metadata":{ "primary":false, "source":{ "type":"CONTACT", "id":"m2" } , "value":"email2@example.com"}}
        ]
    },
    {
        "resourceName":"name2",
        "id":"id2",
        "emailAddresses":[
            { "metadata":{ "primary":true,  "source":{ "type":"FAMILY", "id":"m3" } , "value":"email3@example.com"}},
            { "metadata":{ "primary":false, "source":{ "type":"CONTACT", "id":"m4" } , "value":"email4@example.com"}},
            { "metadata":{ "primary":false, "source":{ "type":"BUSINESS", "id":"m5" } , "value":"email5@example.com"}}
        ]
    },
    {
        "resourceName":"name3",
        "id":"id3",
        "emailAddresses":[
            { "metadata":{ "primary":true,  "source":{ "type":"CONTACT", "id":"m5" } , "value":"email6@example.com"}},
            { "metadata":{ "primary":false, "source":{ "type":"FAMILY", "id":"m6" } , "value":"email7@example.com"}}
        ]
    }
];

const search_email = "email4@example.com";
let parent_key = null;

infos.forEach( info => {
    info.emailAddresses.forEach( ema => {
        if ((ema.metadata.source.type === 'CONTACT') && (ema.metadata.value === search_email )) {
            parent_key = info.id;
        }
    })
});

if ( parent_key === null) {
    console.log('NOT FOUND');
} else {
    console.log('FOUND - PARENT KEY: ', parent_key);
}
```

I can stop the search on the first found state... just need to know if the searched email does exist.

Comment: So, what is your actual question? How to get out of a foreach loop before it has gone over all entries? Well that should be rather trivial to research …

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#some` to iterate through `infos` array, then again use `array#some` to look inside `emailAddresses` array where `source` `type` is `CONTACT` and `value` is the email address you provided.

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

If an element is found, `array#some()` immediately returns true.

```js
const infos =[ { "resourceName":"name1", "id":"id1", "emailAddresses":[ { "metadata":{ "primary":true, "source":{ "type":"CONTACT", "id":"m1" } , "value":"email1@example.com"}}, { "metadata":{ "primary":false, "source":{ "type":"CONTACT", "id":"m2" }, "value":"email2@example.com"}} ] }, { "resourceName":"name2", "id":"id2", "emailAddresses":[ { "metadata":{ "primary":true, "source":{ "type":"FAMILY", "id":"m3" } , "value":"email3@example.com"}}, { "metadata":{ "primary":false, "source":{ "type":"CONTACT","id":"m4" } , "value":"email4@example.com"}}, { "metadata":{ "primary":false, "source":{ "type":"BUSINESS", "id":"m5" } , "value":"email5@example.com"}} ] }, { "resourceName":"name3", "id":"id3", "emailAddresses":[ { "metadata":{ "primary":true, "source":{"type":"CONTACT", "id":"m5" } , "value":"email6@example.com"}}, { "metadata":{ "primary":false, "source":{ "type":"FAMILY", "id":"m6" } , "value":"email7@example.com"}} ] } ],
    searchEmail = "email4@example.com";
    found = infos.some(({emailAddresses}) =>
              emailAddresses.some(({metadata}) => metadata.source.type === 'CONTACT' && metadata.value === searchEmail)
            );
console.log(found);
```

Comment: Just 1 suggestion. Indent the code so its easy to understand. Its a very long code line.

Comment: thanks a lot ... got it and found good doc on it ...  very useful methods, no real need for lodash now ...

Answer (score 0):

The functions some, filter and find all take a function with the same signature. The function passed to some, filter and find receive an item of the array and return true or false.

You can then use partially applied functions and combine them to easily build combinable filters, an example of how that is used can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075368/1641941)

If you need to combine filters then I would suggest having a look at the code below, there are no comments explaining but you can find more information on how it works in the filter example mentioned before.

```js
const infos = [
  {
    "resourceName": "name1",
    "id": "id1",
    "emailAddresses": [
      { "metadata": { "primary": true, "source": { "type": "CONTACT", "id": "m1" }, "value": "email1@example.com" } },
      { "metadata": { "primary": false, "source": { "type": "CONTACT", "id": "m2" }, "value": "email2@example.com" } }
    ]
  },
  {
    "resourceName": "name2",
    "id": "id2",
    "emailAddresses": [
      { "metadata": { "primary": true, "source": { "type": "FAMILY", "id": "m3" }, "value": "email3@example.com" } },
      { "metadata": { "primary": false, "source": { "type": "CONTACT", "id": "m4" }, "value": "email4@example.com" } },
      { "metadata": { "primary": false, "source": { "type": "BUSINESS", "id": "m5" }, "value": "email5@example.com" } }
    ]
  },
  {
    "resourceName": "name3",
    "id": "id3",
    "emailAddresses": [
      { "metadata": { "primary": true, "source": { "type": "CONTACT", "id": "m5" }, "value": "email6@example.com" } },
      { "metadata": { "primary": false, "source": { "type": "FAMILY", "id": "m6" }, "value": "email7@example.com" } }
    ]
  }
];

const filterFn = getter => comparer => o =>
  comparer(getter(o))
;

const getEmailAddresses = o => (o && o.emailAddresses) || [];

const getType = o => o.metadata.source.type;

const getEmail = o => o.metadata.value;

const getPrimary = o => String(o.metadata.primary);

const isEqual = value => item => item === value;

const compareEmail = comparers => items =>
  items.some(
    item=> 
      comparers.reduce(
        (result,comparer)=>result && comparer(item),
        true
      )
  )
;
const getters = [getPrimary,getType,getEmail];
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("select")).forEach(
  select=>{
    select.addEventListener(
      "change",
      ()=>{
        const filters = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("select")).map(
          (select,index)=>
            (select.value==="none")
              ? x=>true
              : filterFn(getters[index])(isEqual(select.value))
        );
        console.log(
          infos.filter(filterFn(getEmailAddresses)(compareEmail(filters)))
          .map(item=>item.resourceName)
        );
      }
    )
  }
)
```

```html
      <select>
        <option value="none">no filter on primary</option>
        <option value="true">primary</option>
        <option value="false">not primary</option>
      </select>
      <select>
        <option value="none">no filter on type</option>
        <option value="CONTACT">CONTACT</option>
        <option value="FAMILY">FAMILY</option>
        <option value="BUSINESS">BUSINESS</option>
      </select>
      <select>
        <option value="none">no filter on email</option>
        <option value="email1@example.com">email1@example.com</option>
        <option value="email2@example.com">email2@example.com</option>
        <option value="email3@example.com">email3@example.com</option>
        <option value="email4@example.com">email4@example.com</option>
        <option value="email5@example.com">email5@example.com</option>
        <option value="email6@example.com">email6@example.com</option>
        <option value="email7@example.com">email7@example.com</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the Array's [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method in combination with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

To safeguard from your code potentially failing when some properties are missing in the Objects of your `infos` Array (i.e. the ones you're searching for), there's a couple of notable things happening in the gist below. They are:

1. In the line of code which reads:

   ```js
   .some(({ emailAddresses = [] }) => emailAddresses
   ```

   *Destructuring* is utilized. However perhaps more importantly, a *default value* of an empty Array (i.e. the `= []` part) has been specified. This will prevent an error if one of your Objects in the `infos` Array doesn't include a `emailAddresses` property. More specifically it will prevent your program failing when the next `.some(...)` method is invoked, (i.e. the one in the subsequent line of code), when there is no `emailAddresses` member/property.
2. The second time the `.some` method is invoked we are not *only* returning a Boolean based on the evaluation of:

   ```js
   metadata.source.type === 'CONTACT' && metadata.value === searchEmail
   ```

   Because just doing this will cause your program to fail when a `metadata` Object in the `emailAddresses` Array doesn't include a `source` member/property. Instead we initially evaluate `metadata.source` to check it's existence before evaluating `metadata.source.type === 'CONTACT'`. So we do this instead:

```js
    metadata.source && metadata.source.type === 'CONTACT' && metadata.value === searchEmail
```

**Note:** Comments 1, and 2 in the code sample below indicate where properties/values have been intentionally omitted to demonstrate the program doesn't fail under such circumstances.

```js
const infos = [{
    "resourceName": "name1",
    "id": "id1"
    // 1. Intentional missing `emailAddresses` property
  }, {
    "resourceName": "name2",
    "id": "id2",
    "emailAddresses": [
      { "metadata": { "primary": true, /* 2. Intentional missing `source` property */ "value": "email3@example.com" } },
      { "metadata": { "primary": false, "source": { "type": "CONTACT", "id": "m1" }, "value": "email4@example.com" } },
      { "metadata": { "primary": false, "source": { "type": "BUSINESS", "id": "m2" }, "value": "email5@example.com" } }
    ]
  }, {
    "resourceName": "name3",
    "id": "id3",
    "emailAddresses": [
      { "metadata": { "primary": true, "source": { "type": "CONTACT", "id": "m3" }, "value": "email6@example.com" } },
      { "metadata": { "primary": false, "source": { "type": "FAMILY", "id": "m4" }, "value": "email7@example.com" } }
    ]
  }
];

const searchEmail = "email4@example.com";

const hasFound = infos
    .some(({ emailAddresses = [] }) => emailAddresses
    .some(({ metadata }) => metadata.source
        && metadata.source.type === 'CONTACT'
        && metadata.value === searchEmail
    ));

console.log(hasFound);
```

**An alternative way to safeguard your code:**

Alternatively, *Nested Object Destructuring* with *default values* can be utilised to help safeguard your code from failing when the properties that you’re searching for don’t exist in the `infos` Array of Objects. For example:

```
const hasFound = infos
    .some(({ emailAddresses = [] }) => emailAddresses
    .some(({ metadata: { source = {}, value } }) =>
        source.type === 'CONTACT' && value === searchEmail
    ));
```

This time in the second `.some()` method we *destructure*/navigate into the nested object to retrieve only the information we need, i.e. `source` and `value`. By doing this we avoid the need to check-for `metadata.source`‘s existence , (i.e. when returning the Boolean from the function as per the previous gist), because the `source` variable gets assigned a default value of an empty Object (i.e. `source = {}`).