# How to remove strings from an array of strings which doesn't contain search keyword?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've an array(`testArray`) of strings. I need to remove the strings from array which doesn't contain at least one of the `searchTerms`.`testArray` should ignore case of `searchTerms`.

**EDIT:** Result array should include the string even the search term is part of a word in the string.

eg:`"someright text"` should be included in the result.

```js
var testArray = [
    "I am",
    "I am wrong and I don't know",
    "I am right and I know",
    "I don't know",
    "some text",
    "I do know"
  ],
  searchTerms = ["I", "right","know"] //or ["i", "right","know"];

$.each(searchTerms, function(index, term) {
  var regX = new RegExp(term, "i");
  testArray = $.map(testArray, function(item) {
    if (regX.test(item)) {
      return item;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
});

console.log(testArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The result should be as below,

```
testArray = [
        "I am",
        "I am wrong and I don't know",
        "I am right and I know",
        "I don't know",           
        "I do know"
      ]
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that is all the search terms are found, then and only then it's a valid term

Comment: [The following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075368/1641941) should help you out. It uses filer so it doesn't change your array but creates a new one where data is filtered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var testArray = ["I am", "I am wrong and I don't know", "I am right and I know", "I don't know", "some text", "I do know"],
searchTerms = ["I", "right","know"];

searchTerms = searchTerms.map(w => w.toLowerCase());

/* Use filter to filter only those records which have the search term in it. */
var result = testArray.filter((s) => s.split(" ").some((w) => searchTerms.includes(w.toLowerCase())));

console.log(result);
```

**EDIT**

```js
var testArray = ["I am", "I am wrong and I don't know", "I am right and I know", "I don't know", "some text", "I do know", "someright"],
searchTerms = ["I", "right","know"];

searchTerms = searchTerms.map(w => w.toLowerCase());

/* Use filter to filter only those records which have the search term in it. */
var result = testArray.filter((s) => searchTerms.some(w => s.toLowerCase().includes(w)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The regex was case insensitive and uses the testArray as a source to create a regular expression so strictly speaking this doesn't do what the OP requires. If testArray item only needs to contain a word of searchTerms then converting everything to lower or upper case would work.

Comment: @HMR - It depended on the OP and OP agrees with you. Hence, updated my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Raviteja - I have updated the answer for case insensitive search.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal. This is not working if search keyword is part of a word like `"someright text"`.

Comment: @Raviteja - Updated

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use `s.toLowerCase().indexOf(w) !== -1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the code would look like adapting the code in the comment to your situation, the getter just returns a value from the array and not a property of the value.

```js
testArray = [
  "I am",
  "I am wrong and I don't know",
  "I am right and I know",
  "I don't know",           
  "I do know"
];
const filterFn = getter => comparer => o =>
  comparer(getter(o));

//you are not getting a property of an object item in the array but the value
const getValue = o => o;

// compare search contains word
const containsWord = search => {
  //small optimization
  const searchAsRegExp = search.map(s=>new RegExp(s,"i"));
  return value =>
    searchAsRegExp.some(reg=>reg.test(value));
};

console.log(
  `using containsWord(["I", "right","know"])`,
  testArray.filter(filterFn(getValue)(containsWord(["I", "right","know"])))
)
```